# R lattice title font size

Tags: r, lattice

I need my title on the graph to look like the following

```
Main

Submain
```

where main is of a different font size than submain, right now I have it as main="Main \n submain" but how do I specify different sizes.  If not, how do I add another title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of those tasks are super easy with lattice; but that doesn't mean it's impossible. In addition to accepting character values for the `main=` parameter, it can also accept an arbitrary `grid` object (or `grob`). Lattice is build on the `grid` graphics library so you can customize many things before plotting. Here's one solution that uses a helper function to create `grid` object with two rows of text.

```
library(lattice)
library(grid)

doubleTitle <- function(a,b) {
    gTree(children=gList(
        textGrob(a, gp=gpar(fontsize=15, fontface=2), y=0, 
            vp=viewport(layout.pos.row=1, layout.pos.col=1)),
        textGrob(b, gp=gpar(fontsize=13, fontface=3), y=0, 
            vp=viewport(layout.pos.row=2, layout.pos.col=1))
    ), vp=viewport(layout=grid.layout(nrow=2, ncol=1)), cl="doubletitle")
}

heightDetails.doubletitle <- function(x, recording=T) {
    Reduce(`+`, lapply(x$children, grid:::heightDetails.text)) * 2
}
```

And we can use it with

```
xyplot(1:10~1:10, main=doubleTitle("Main","Submain"))
```

[image]

You can clearly see the `fontsize=` options. For `fontface=`, 1 is normal, 2 is bold, 3 is italic, and 4 is bold+italic. To change the spacing between rows, adjust the value of `2` in the `heightDetails.doubletitle` function.

Comment: Thank you very helpful.  I was using xlab.top for subtitle but this is much more robust

Answer (score 0):

While I strongly prefer MrFlick solution, I want to add another possibility based on the fact that `main=` can also accept expression arguments

```
xyplot(1:10~1:10, 
  main = expression(atop(bold(Main~Title), italic(scriptstyle(Sub~Title))))
)
```