# Subscript in axis label when a line break is included?

Tags: r

I've gone round in circles with this.

What I would like is the axis label to read "Difference in relative oxygen consumption" with "(V0sub(2peak))" below [the '2peak' in subscript]. I've tried substitute, bquote and a number of different combinations with expression and paste/paste0, whenever I have the link break in there it seems to add a large gap before the subscript "2peak".

```
qplot(1:10)+
labs(x="", y=expression(paste0("Difference in relative oxygen consumption\n",(V0[2][peak]))))
```

Using paste instead of paste0 will get around having the big gap, but then the second line is right aligned.

Thanks

Comment: "Math mode" does not properly recognize control characters such as `\n` (from `?plotmath`). I'm assuming `labs(x="", y=expression("Difference in relative oxygen consumption"~(V0[2][peak])))` just isn't pretty enough?

Comment: Yeah, it's more a consistency thing with the other graphs I'm generating, long titles looks nice with the titles all on the line below etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` is generally not needed and even confuses things. If you read the ?plotmath page you see that you cannot get linefeeds with `\n`. The `atop` plotmath function can be used:

```
    qplot(1:10)+ labs(x="", y=expression(atop(
            Difference~'in'~relative~oxygen~consumption,
            "("*V0[`2peak`]*")")) )
```

Your intent w.r.t. the O\sub2 and "peak" was not clear.  One glitch was that the word "in" is reserved which was why  it needed to be quoted. The parser does not recognize tokens with initial digits which was why the '2peak' needed quoting.

Comment: Thanks, atop() was one I hadn't run into yet on my way down the rabbit hole. I did catch the 'in' issue and had a feeling from past work that leading numbers caused issues. I'll leave this open for now as this still is a bit of an undesired solution, given the relativity of the line spacing is lost by forcing this into a 'top/bottom' formula. Hopefully there's another solution out there.

Answer (score 0):

I think @BondedDust's suggestion is best, but I also adapted [a solution for a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019075/r-lattice-title-font-size/25026959#25026959) to possibly work as well. Here we do some pretty low-level grob hacking.

```
#helper function
library(grid)
doubleYTitle <- function(a,b) {
    gTree(children=gList(
        textGrob(a, gp=gpar(fontsize=13, fontface=2), y=.5, x=0, 
            vp=viewport(layout.pos.row=1, layout.pos.col=1), rot=90),
        textGrob(b, gp=gpar(fontsize=12, fontface=1), y=.5, x=0,
            vp=viewport(layout.pos.row=1, layout.pos.col=2), rot=90)
    ), vp=viewport(layout=grid.layout(nrow=1, ncol=2)), cl="doubleytitle")
}

widthDetails.doubleytitle <- function(x, recording=T) {
    Reduce(`+`, lapply(x$children, grid:::widthDetails.text)) * 5
}
```

Now we put it to use

```
gg <- qplot(1:10)+labs(x="", y="Difference")
gb <- ggplot_build(gg)
gt <- ggplot_gtable(gb)
xx <- doubleYTitle("Difference in relative oxygen consumption",
    expression((V0[2][peak])))
gt$grobs[[7]]<-xx
plot(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm optimistic about this approach, couldn't get the width multiple "* 5" to work though.

Comment: Actually, i was trying to test that before I posted and forgot. I could not get that to work either. For some reason it doesn't seem to be calling the `widthDetails.doubleytitle` function at all. It will probably take a lot of digging for me to figure this out. If it's OK if it takes a few days, let me know. Otherwise I might not bother.

Comment: Yeah sure, that's fine. I mean, at present I don't believe there's a guide to a solution for this out there, so it would be good to have it available.